# This localhost page can't be found in vue 3 + vitejs after a successful update

Tags: vuejs3, vite

In a vue3 app, I create a resource and I route to the resource created where the user should input additional data. The resource creation are redirection work fine. On the form the submit with additional data calls a `PUT` to update the data in the backend and response is the updated resource. However after the response is resolved, this redirects me to a 404 localhost page can't be found:

My resource.vue file

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Resource</h1>
            <form @submit="updateResource" method="post">
                <div class="mb3">
                    <label for="text1" class="form-label">Text1</label>
                    <input type="text" clas="form-control" id="text1" v-model="resource.text1">
                </div>
                <div class="mb3">
                    <label for="text2" class="form-label">Text2</label>
                    <input type="text" clas="form-control" id="text2" v-model="resource.text2">
                </div>
                <button type="Submit">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import ResourceDataServices from '../services/ResourceDataServices'

    export default{
        data() {
            return {
                resource: {
                    text1: null,
                    text2: null
                }
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.$watch(
                () => this.$route.params,
                () => {
                    this.fetchResourceById(this.$route.params.id)
                },
                { immediate: true }
            )
        },
        methods: {
            fetchResourceById(id){
                this.release = null             
                ResourceDataServices.get(id)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.resource= response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            },
            updateResource(){
                ResourceDataServices.update(this.release.id, this.release)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.resource = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The resourceDataService is a simple service task

```
import http from "../http-common";

class ResourceDataService {

    get(id) {
        return http.get(`/resource/${id}`)
    }

    update(id, data) {
        return http.put(`/resource/${id}`, data);
    }

}

export default new ResourceDataService();
```

So when I navigate to that page for instance:

http://localhost:5173/#/resource/cbd0ac53-bb8e-4bc3-b132-8552fff2b3b8

I have my form to fill, when I click on save I get the following `404`

This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:5173/#/resource/cbd0ac53-bb8e-4bc3-b132-8552fff2b3b8

If I press `F5` nothing happens, however if I go in the url bar and press enter then it loads the resource.

What am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to prevent the default action of submit event ,if you dont want to jump some other web pages

```js
updateResource(e){
    e.preventDefault();
                ResourceDataServices.update(this.release.id, this.release)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.resource = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Forms are designed to direct to another page after submission. To prevent this in vue you have to add an event modifier. Simply change this

```
<form @submit="updateResource" method="post">
```

**To this**

```
<form @submit.prevent="updateResource" method="post">
```

The . prevent actually modifies the submit event. This will stop your form from redirecting.